# HTTP Status 403 - For Spring MVC Page on Post Operation

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, spring

I am having this issue where I am able to display a Page using Spring MVC Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/example/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showForm() {
    System.out.println("#############Hellooo I was here#################");
    return new ModelAndView("user", "user", new UserForm());
}
```

This is displaying a `user.jsp` as expected. Now from this `User.Jsp` I am submitting a form which is like this

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Welcome, Enter The Employee Details</h3>
        <form:form method="POST" action="/example/userdetails" modelAttribute="user">
             <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="firstName">Name</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="firstName"/></td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="email">Email</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="email"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Upon submission I was expecting this page to display another page but I keep getting this error

```
HTTP Status 403 -

type Status report

message

description Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.39
```

For some reason the control doesn't seem to be going to this method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/example/userdetails", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit(@ModelAttribute("user")UserForm user, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
    System.out.println("#############Hellooo I was here ->submit#################");
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "error";
    }
    model.addAttribute("firstName", user.getFirstName());
    model.addAttribute("email", user.getEmail());
    return "view";
}
```

Do with DXA/Tridion web app we need to do some settings to enable `Post` operations? As `Get` seems to be working fine.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the way the DXA Audience Manager modules handles forms? https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/blob/release/1.7/webapp-java/dxa-module-audience-manager-abstract/src/main/java/com/sdl/dxa/modules/audience/controller/AudienceController.java

Comment: This Seems to be similar to what I am doing. Not sure why would a POST wont work

Answer (score 3):

Got it working.

Basically, It seems that forms in DXA need to be tied to csrf-token. So inside your form include this tag

```
    <dxa:csrf-token/>
```

to something like

```
 <form method="POST" action="/example/userdetails" >
    <dxa:csrf-token/>
         <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label path="firstName">Name</label></td>
                <td><input path="name"/></td>
            </tr>....
```

Hope the Documentation was explicitly stating that CSRF Token is required for all post operations. (*I could have avoided 2 days of frustration :P*)

Comment: The docs do mention how to disable CSRF protection (obviously not recommended): http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v7/GUID-F51DCF89-451A-4D69-BA9C-801D3D17A6D0

Comment: +1 Abhishek. The right thing to do is to submit the csrf token, not disable the protection as per the docs. I too wish the recommended approach was provided in the docs. There used to be a way to leave comments in the docs, but I don't see that option enabled anymore.